# Define a property of a base class (ascx) in a custom UserControl, and instanciate a child class in the aspx

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, properties, ascx, base-class

I defined 3 custom usercontrols like that :

```
public partial abstract class MyAbstractControl : Usercontrol{
  // Base class definition here, with common property and methods
  public string CommonAttribute {get; set;}
}

public partial class MyConcreteControl1 : MyAbstractControl{
  // Some specific stuff here
}

public partial class MyConcreteControl2 : MyAbstractControl{
  // Other specific but different stuff here
}
```

Then I defined another UserControl that have a property of the base class :

```
public partial class MyBeautifulControl : UserControl{
  [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
  public MyAbstractControl ChildElement{get;set;}
}
```

In the aspx file, I'm using this control, but I'd like to define an instance of **MyConcreteControl1** instead of **MyAbstractControl**

But If I write :

```
<MyBeautifulControl runat="server" id="beautiful">
  <ChildElement commonAttribute="value" />
</MyBeautifulControl>
```

The **ChildElement** can only be defined as a **MyAbstractControl** instance. I'd like to create a **MyConcreteControl1** or an **MyConcreteControl2** instance, depending on the context, and I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `System.Web.UI.TemplateContainerAttribute`:

```
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty), 
 TemplateContainer(typeof(MyConcreteControl))]
public MyAbstractControl ChildElement{get;set;}
```

see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontainerattribute.aspx) for details. There is also a [HOWTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) about.

Comment: If I do what you propose, I need to know in advance that I'll instantiate a MyConcreteControl1 in the ChildElement property, right ?

Comment: I don't need a way to display same model with different templates, but I need to instantiate different objects with different properties.